# LDAP Auto-registration user blocking

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have LDAP enabled on my Joomla Server. The thing is when LDAP creates a user in Joomla, it is automatically activated. Where does it set the value of block? I want to pre-configure the code for every user that is created by LDAP to be blocked first and require admin's activation.

Comment: I've never used LDAP before, but to have an admin activate the account, this is done in the User Manager option in the Joomla backend. Have you tried this yet?

Comment: I have no problems with Joomla's registration flow. The only thing is when we use LDAP in registering, the process is this: user logs in credentials that is found in the Active Directory. If it exists in the Directory, it creates the user automatically to joomla's database. However, the user created by LDAP is automatically activated. I can't find the code where we can set the value of activation to false so when a new user is created by LDAP, it would be the same with joomla's flow of registration.

Comment: `plugins\authentication\ldap\ldap.php` and `plugins\authentication\ldap\ldap.php` are the only files I can imagine are involved in this process

Comment: @Lodder those 2 you mentioned is the same file.

Comment: Oops, the other is `libraries\joomla\client\ldap.php`

Comment: unfortunately it does not have what I need. I think LDAP also uses Joomla's create user except the user is already activated when saved to the database. I'm thinking of creating a trigger in my MySQL database that whenever a new user is created, i would just update it to block / deactivate the user.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you an other idea how we build a similar construct for our joomla based installations around the world:

1.) Go to the "Viewing Access Levels", and open the "Registred" users ACL menu entry:

[image]

2.) Copy that one and name it "approved-users"

[image]

3.)
In the global settings change the default access level to "approved-users"
[image]

3.)
Reconfigure your side (modules, pages, menus, ...) so that only the access level "approved-users" can use them. Here is an example for that section for an module entry:

[image]

4.)
You also could configure a default page only for the user group "registred" which said "Sorry, but an administrator need to approve your account, come back tomorrow".

There is really no "hack" from some Joomla core files needed ;-)